# Change location _viminfo file on Windows

Tags: vim

I use gvim 7.2 script dev and other admin work on a Windows XP laptop and it has picked my network share as the location of the _viminfo.  This is problematic because it takes a long time for vim to start.
Is there a way to change the location of _viminfo file with out modifying my environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `viminfo` option to set the location of your `_viminfo`.  eg

```
:set viminfo=nC:\\_viminfo
```

More information is available from Vim's online help ...

```
:help viminfo
```

Comment: That sort of worked.  I had to add the value for the ' char, not sure why but it worked.

Comment: Yeah, not quite.  Edit "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc" and add "set viminfo+=nc:\\_viminfo".  That seems to have worked.

Comment: It seems that the + adds on to the default value and (as the above commenter mentioned) you need the ' value so I am guessing it is required (probably mentioned in the docs somewhere).  So this also worked "set viminfo='100,nc:\\_viminfo"

Answer (score 2):

The `$HOME` on your login mapped to the network drive is probably causing this.

The easiest way to override this it with an alias that makes `vim` pick a specific viminfo file.

```
vim -i _viminfo
```

However, if you choose `C:\` as the path for your viminfo file on a shared machine, the next person trying the same trick may pickup your viminfo file. So, it might be prudent to use,

```
vim -i _vim-yourname
```

Finally, to get this working on your machine, you can make a shortcut to `vim` that has the `-i` setting defined in it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows, simplest thing to do is use setlocal, endlocal and set your home drive to something else in between.

for example, 
edit your C:\Windows\vim.bat

at top, add line

```
setlocal
REM then set your home drive to something local like C: or D
set HOMEDRIVE=D:

REM at bottom final line should be:
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite a while now, but I am just mentioning this for future readers.

I was facing the same issue while trying to change the location for viminfo file in vimrc. At last setting the value of `viminfofile` option worked for me.

Added the following to my vimrc:

```
set viminfofile=D:\vim\viminfo
```

*It works for me on windows with vim 8.2*